# Apache2 and .psp files

Tags: python, apache2

I have a server setup, and working.  Trying to get add python scripting support.  I seem to have it working, but how do I configure Apache2 to look for index.psp with out me needing to be specific. Meaning, I can specify index.psp, and it works, but I want apache to search for index.html, then index.php, and then also look for index.psp.  How do I include .psp in the search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `DirectoryIndex index.html index.psp index.psp` ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)).

Comment: umm, it was that simple, wow.  thanks for the quick response.